# Escape backslash and double quote in mongo $text

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a problem with mongo $text $search a phrase. So i want to create a $search phrase from my variable. $search phrase should look like this: "\"search\"". So in javascript we can escape quote and backslash just adding one more slash: `'\\\"search\\\"'`. But if we print or pass it somewhere we will get different results in different environments. In browser we will get `'\"search\"'` in node js (5.x) we will get this `'\\"search\\"`. What is the matter? 
My final goal is built $search string for using in mongoDB $text operator. Maybe somebody can help me with it or with my question above.

Comment: Perhaps you should show a case we can reproduce so it's easy to point to the part of your code process that needs correcting. Show an example of where you are sending the string from and how.

Comment: Sure. Here is example. http://jsbin.com/wagitibeca/edit?js,console   and after try to put that code into browser's console.

Answer (score 2):

(I know it's late, but I want to answer in case someone will find this page looking for a way to solve this problem)

You don't have to write it with the right Javascript format. Just leave it as it is in MongoShell

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:'\"search\"'}}, function...
```

So, a good way to approach a generic string is

```
var search = "generic phrase to search";
search = '\"' + search.split(' ').join('\" \"') + '\"';
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:search}}, function...
```

Hope it's helpful.